# Why do we Define Complex Exponentiation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, soft-question

In complex analysis we define complex exponentiation by the (often) multivalued expression $z^w = e^{w\log{z}}$. This makes intuitive sense to me, but right off the bat it leads to some strange results. For example, if $\alpha$ is an irrational real number, the expression $e^{\alpha}$ can be viewed in two different ways: It can be seen as either the image of $\alpha$ under the single-valued complex exponential function, or through the above definition, where it has infinitely many values.

This feels inelegant to me -- what's the purpose of even defining $z^w$ in the first place?

Comment: Well for instance you might want to define a square root function.

Comment: I wonder if this was a motivation behind the notation $\exp(\alpha).$

Comment: "it has infinitely values": you should forget about multivalued functions, they don't exist. You fix a branch of $\log$, either on the whole of $\Bbb{C}^*$ or just on an open subset $U$ of it, then you can define $z^w$ for $z\in U$, and (if your branch is analytic on $U$) you can consider its analytic continuation along any curve from $U$ not passing through $0$, which amounts to change the branch of $\log$.